# Strapi v4 won't fetch image(or any media) columns from a related field

Tags: sqlite, strapi

I'm trying to fetch a single category using slug

http://localhost:1337/api/categories/{slug}

In my controller:

```
 async findOne(ctx) {     
     const {id : slug} = ctx.params     
         const response = await strapi.db
           .query("api::category.category")
           .findOne({
             where: { slug: slug },
             populate: {
               blogs: {
                 select: ["id", "title"],
                 orderBy: ["id"],
               },
             },
           });
```

This works fine... but when add another field

```
select: ["id", "title", "image"],
```

I get the error

> error: select distinct `t1`.`blog_order`, `t0`.`id`, `t0`.`id`,
> `t0`.`title`, `t0`.`image`, `t1`.`category_id` from `blogs` as `t0`
> left join `categories_blogs_links` as `t1` on `t0`.`id` =
> `t1`.`blog_id` where (`t1`.`category_id` in (2)) order by `t0`.`id`
> asc, `t1`.`blog_order` asc - no such column: t0.image SqliteError:
> select distinct `t1`.`blog_order`, `t0`.`id`, `t0`.`id`, `t0`.`title`,
> `t0`.`image`, `t1`.`category_id` from `blogs` as `t0` left join
> `categories_blogs_links` as `t1` on `t0`.`id` = `t1`.`blog_id` where
> (`t1`.`category_id` in (2)) order by `t0`.`id` asc, `t1`.`blog_order`
> asc - no such column: t0.image

but there IS a field called "image"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

really fun ussage of populate, have't thought actually that you can orderBy and select inside populate hmm.

The problem you have it's likely due to that you have to also explicitly populate relations inside. Try this:

```js
.findOne({
   where: { slug: slug },
   populate: {
     blogs: {
       populate: ["image"],
       select: ["id", "title", "image"],
       orderBy: ["id"],
     },
   },
```

Comment: Yep. i figure this one out after checking the .db file. I implemented it slightly different. Please check my answer if you could

Answer (score 0):

The reason I'm getting this error is because the media fields are not stored in database, so the sqlite is looking for a column that does not exists.
So we may have to populate it seperately.

```
const {id : slug} = ctx.params     
         const data = await strapi.db
           .query("api::category.category")
           .findOne({
             where: { slug: slug },
             populate: {
               blogs: {               
                 select: ["id", "title", "publish_date","slug"],
                 orderBy: ["publish_date"],
                 populate:{"image" : true}
               },
             
             },
           });
```

Comment: Yea it’s ok, the populate takes an object like `{image:true}` or an array of string like: `['image']`